# Implement mouse input with opencv on an image

Tags: python, opencv

I found some code online and I changed it a little. I am doing a navigation project and want user to input a start and end point by clicking on the map image. Here is what I have:

```
import cv2 as cv2

def draw_circle(event,x,y,flags,param):
    global mouseX,mouseY
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
        cv2.circle(img,(x,y),2,(0,0,0),-1)
        mouseX,mouseY = x,y

img = cv2.imread("1.png")
img = cv2.resize(g1,(800,600))
cv2.namedWindow('image')
cv2.setMouseCallback('image',draw_circle)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
```

Normally we need a `cv2.waitKey()` for this image to be shown, but in this case, I really don't know what to do next.

I want to show this map view, and when user double-click on it, it will show a black dot(this is implemented). After user input two points, the image will close and the function will return two sets of pixel wise coordinate indicate where did the user click.

I saw people putting `cv2.imshow()` and `cv2.waitKey()` in a while loop, this will show the image and the click function is working fine as well. But I don't know how to return the pixel coordinate in that way.

Comment: uhm, I noticed an indentation error on the above code, it was a mistake when I type the code in StackOverflow

Comment: You can always edit your post.

Comment: Oh, I see your update! Thanks!

Comment: I have already editted your post. There should be the `edit` button between `share` and `flag` buttons.

Comment: The code you posted already has `mouseX` and `mouseY`, which are the coordinates of the clicked point. Just add `last_mouseX` and `last_mouseY` to save the last clicked point.

Comment: You should be using [`cv2.waitKey()`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=waitkey#waitkey) even if it is not in a loop in order to display the image.

Comment: I am a little confused, when I try to do like `last_mouseX = mouseX` in the bottom of my code, it will say `NameError: name 'mouseX' is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import cv2 as cv2

def draw_circle(event,x,y,flags,param):
    global mouseX,mouseY
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
        cv2.circle(img,(x,y),2,(0,0,0),-1)
        mouseX,mouseY = x,y
        cv2.destroyWindow('image')
        print('last position: ', mouseX, mouseY)

img = cv2.imread("1.jpg")
img = cv2.resize(img, (800,600))
cv2.namedWindow('image')
cv2.setMouseCallback('image',draw_circle)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

If you run, this code, it will register the last position the mouse, destory the window and print the result the console. The trick you, should use the `x` and `y` provided by the callback funtion. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

def mouse_callback(event, x, y, flags, param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        global mouseX, mouseY, last_mouseX, last_mouseY
        last_mouseX, last_mouseY = mouseX, mouseY
        mouseX, mouseY = x, y
        print("x =", mouseX, "\ty =", mouseY)
        print("last_x =", last_mouseX, "last_y =", last_mouseY)
        global disp_img
        disp_img = np.copy(img)
        cv2.circle(disp_img, (mouseX,mouseY), 2, (0,0,255), -1)
        cv2.circle(disp_img, (last_mouseX,last_mouseY), 2, (255,0,0), -1)

mouseX, mouseY, last_mouseX, last_mouseY = 0, 0, 0, 0
img = cv2.imread('ip.jpg')
disp_img = np.copy(img)
winname = 'image'
cv2.namedWindow(winname)
cv2.setMouseCallback(winname, mouse_callback)
# we need to loop imshow in order to draw the circle
ch = 0
while ch != 27:  # press esc to exit
    cv2.imshow('image', disp_img)
    ch = cv2.waitKey(1)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```